# JQuery slides: fade effect

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am using the JQuery slides that you can find here http://www.slidesjs.com/examples/standard/

but the fade effect is not working on play, only on navigation !

```
<script>
    $(function() {
      $('#slides').slidesjs({
        width: 800,
        height: 400,
        play: {
          active: true,
          auto: true,
          interval: 3500,
          effect: {
          fade: {
            speed: 1000
          }
        }
          //swap: true
        },
        navigation: {
          effect: "fade"
        },
        pagination: {
          effect: "fade"
        },
        effect: {
          fade: {
            speed: 1000
          }
        }
      });
    });
  </script>
```

I also tried to remove the speed from the first part of your code will get the fade working on initial play.

```
$('#slides').slidesjs({
  width: 800,
  height: 400,
  play: {
    active: true,
    auto: true,
    interval: 3500,
    effect: "fade"
    //swap: true
  },
  navigation: {
    effect: "fade"
  },
  pagination: {
    effect: "fade"
  },
  effect: {
    fade: {
      speed: 1000
    }
  }
});
```

Comment: Enclose your code in a `$(document).ready( function() { //code });` and it should work.

Comment: the slides work, only the fade effect between images does not work

Comment: Can you put together a live example? I know you linked to the docs but they work, whatever you're doing isn't. So we need to see your version.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've made this work.  Per the [docs](http://www.slidesjs.com/#examples), you can set the `effect` property for `play` to a *string*.

Check out the jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/cale_b/5ac1cebL/

```
$(function() {
  $('#slides').slidesjs({
    width: 800,
    height: 400,
    play: {
      active: true,
      auto: true,
      interval: 500,
      // within the play property, effect should be a string, i.e. "fade"
      effect: "fade"
    },
    navigation: {
      effect: "fade"
    },
    pagination: {
      effect: "fade"
    },
    effect: {
      fade: {
        speed: 1000
      }
    }
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Removing the speed from the first part of your code will get the fade working on initial play.

```js
$('#slides').slidesjs({
  width: 800,
  height: 400,
  play: {
    active: true,
    auto: true,
    interval: 3500,
    effect: "fade"
    //swap: true
  },
  navigation: {
    effect: "fade"
  },
  pagination: {
    effect: "fade"
  },
  effect: {
    fade: {
      speed: 1000
    }
  }
});
```